# Why Hive UDF not working with "Create Table as" query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-udf

I have written a UDF that works fine with select query. I have registered UDF with database 'db1' permanantly
Eg. `select  db1.myUDF(column name, arg) from table_name;`
but when I am trying to create a new table from it, new table did not reflect changes.
Query I tried is

```
create table names_perf_CBC_9 as 
    select db1.myUDF(id,arg2) as id, name 
    from names_perf 
    limit 2;
```

Does Create Table query support custom UDF ??

**Edit:**

myUDF was supposed to encrypt a string. It does encrypt and I can see that in select query. but can not in new table created using "create table as" query.
inbuild UDF eg `upper` works fine too.

names_perf is a managed table create from external table names_text_perf which is create from external csv

Comment: unless it is absolutely necessary to use `create table as`, why don't you create first and then use `insert into table`

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "new table did not reflect changes"?

Comment: @serge_k I have added comments in question.